# Paypal via Datacash

Tags: paypal, datacash

When making Paypal payment requests via Datacash it is required to provide a `client` and a `password`, as explained in the [documentation page](http://www.datacash.com/mcdatacash/implementation_guides/Express-Checkout.html):

> Each transaction type requires specific information to be provided. In addition to those listed, each requires a client and password - these are security details which identify your account.

Where can I find them in my [Paypal Developer Dashboard](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/myapps)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you must send to support@datacash.com your paypal account details (username / password / signature) which you can find in the [Accounts page](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/accounts) by clicking on the "Profile" of your business account.

Then Datacash support will enable Paypal on your Datacash and send you back the appropriate client number and password.